# R lubridate: weekdays in local language

Tags: r, locale, lubridate

How can I get the weekdays and month in my local language?

My code:

```
library(lubridate)
data <- c("10-02-2015", "11-03-2015")
data.lubri <- dmy(data)
wday(data.lubri, label=TRUE)
```

Always returns

```
[1] Tues Wed 
Levels: Sun < Mon < Tues < Wed < Thurs < Fri < Sat
```

and

```
month(data.lubri, label = TRUE)
```

Always returns

```
[1] Feb Mar
Levels: Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr < May < Jun < Jul < Aug < Sep < Oct < Nov < Dec
```

I need it in Portuguese, using lubridate, and already tried a ton of locale options, but nothing lubridate related seems to work.

The base functions, weekdays() and months(), work, though.

The problem is base months() gives me a unordered vector when working with dates.

I need them as an ordered factor, for later plotting.

My current work around is getting my hands dirty:

```
factor(months(data.lubri, abbreviate=TRUE), 
             levels = c("Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", 
                        "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"), 
             ordered=TRUE)


[1] Fev Mar
Levels: Jan < Fev < Mar < Abr < Mai < Jun < Jul < Ago < Set < Out < Nov < Dez
```

but this isn't classy...

Comment: Create a lookup table of the translations and `merge()`.

Comment: Do you have some strange aversion against base functions?

Comment: hahahha, nope. The thing is: base months returns me a unordered vector, while lubridate month returns me a ordered factor. Its better for plotting by month.

Comment: You can easily wrap your approach in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@erickfis,

I created a function that generalizes your approach to any locale, as I have faced the same problem frequently:

```
months2<-function(date){
x<-format(ISOdate(1970, 1:12, 1), "%B")
factor(months(date),ordered=TRUE,levels=x)
}
```

Comment: sorry but I couldn't get this running. `months2("10-10-2010") or 
months2("2017-10-10") will give me this error: 
 Error in UseMethod("months") : 
  método não aplicável para 'months' aplicado a um objeto de classe "character" `

Comment: @erickfis, the argument must be a datetime object. You can add a line to the function to make the conversion before running the rest of the code, but I don't think this is a good idea. The best approach should be converting the character string to datetime before running the function, as you did in your example: `data.lubri <- dmy(data)`

Answer (score 4):

Current versions of lubridate (at least 1.7.1) allow this by default:

```
wday(x, label = FALSE, abbr = TRUE,
  week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 7),
  locale = Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"))
```

In older versions, you can do simply add labels to the factor variable that hold your week days (Dutch in this example):

```
variable <- factor(variable, levels = c('Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'), labels = c('Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag'))
```