# Optimize code for scatter plot generation in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

The executable code below generates a scatter plot that depends on the date (`date2`) he chooses and three lines are also generated, referring to mean, mean+standard deviation and mean-standard deviation, which are based on the day of the week (`Week`) that is chosen.

As you can see, I used vector `i` to generate the mean and standard deviation. But I would like to optimize this, that is, when he chooses the date, he already understands what day of the week it is, so he doesn't need to use this `i` vector.

For example, I put it to generate scatterplot date 10/04/2021, so the code would need to know it's a Saturday, without having to set vector `i` to 3.

Can you help me with this question?

The link to download the database is:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W_hzuRq7D6X12BdwaXeM-cjg2A5MIKDx/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102073768617937039119&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df<-read_excel('C:/Users/Downloads/database_test1.xlsx')

df<-subset(df,df$date2<df$date1) 

dim_data<-dim(df)

day<-c(seq.Date(from = as.Date(df$date2[1]),
                to = as.Date(df$date2[dim_data[1]]),
                by = "1 day"))

df_grouped <- df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date)) %>% 
  group_by(date2) %>% 
  summarise(Id = first(Id),
            date1 = first(date1),
            Week = first(Week),
            D = first(D),
            D1 = sum(D1)) %>% 
  select(Id,date1,date2,Week,D,D1)

df_grouped <- df_grouped %>% mutate(date1=format(date1,"%d/%m/%Y"),
                                    date2=format(date2,"%d/%m/%Y"))
df_grouped<-data.frame(df_grouped)

DS=c("Thursday","Friday","Saturday") 

i<-3
df_OC<-subset(df_grouped,is.na(D)) 
ds_OC<-subset(df_OC,df_OC$Week==DS[i])

#Mean and Standard Deviation
mean_Week<-mean(as.numeric(ds_OC[,"D1"]) )
sdeviation_Week<-sd(as.numeric(ds_OC[,"D1"]))

#create scatter plot
scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
  dta %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dt)) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
    plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7),
         ylim = c((min(.$val) %/% 10) * 10, (max(.$val) %/% 10 + 1) * 15))
    abline(h=mean_Week, col='blue') 
    abline(h=(mean_Week + sdeviation_Week), col='green',lty=2) 
    abline(h=(mean_Week - sdeviation_Week), col='orange',lty=2)
}  

scatter_date("2021-04-10",df)
```

**Generated images**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a lookup table:

```r
library(tibble)

lookup <- df %>% 
  select(date2, Week) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(date2 = ymd(date2)) %>% 
  deframe()

lookup
#> 2021-03-04 2021-04-02 2021-04-03 2021-04-08 2021-04-09 2021-04-10 
#> "Thursday"   "Friday" "Saturday" "Thursday"   "Friday" "Saturday"
```

So now

```r
lookup["2021-04-10"]
#> "Saturday"
```

To use this with your scatterplot function you need to move some of your code into your function.

---

One more idea of optimization:

```r
# You could put this lines into one pipe
df_grouped <- df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date)) %>% 
  group_by(date2) %>% 
  summarise(Id = first(Id),
            date1 = first(date1),
            Week = first(Week),
            D = first(D),
            D1 = sum(D1)) %>% 
  select(Id, date1, date2, Week, D, D1) %>% 
  mutate(date1 = format(date1, "%d/%m/%Y"),
         date2 = format(date2, "%d/%m/%Y"))

# you don't need this line
# df_grouped<-data.frame(df_grouped)
```

Two more hints:

1. Use a space after ",". This makes the code easier to read.
2. Avoid using different types of quoting marks: use either " or ' not both (unless you *have* to use both).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Martin! Liked it! But I was confused about what the scatter_date function will look like. If that doesn't bother you, could you enter the code for this part as you thought or the entire code?

Comment: Perhaps tomorrow. I need to sleep now.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68948847/8282674 you can adapt your `scatter_date` with a switch statment and calculate every mean in there. The other way with less changes in your code, would be to remove `DS=c("Thursday","Friday","Saturday")`  to calculate the weekday in the `scatter_date` function directly:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df<-readxl::read_excel('C:/Users/Downloads/database_test1.xlsx')

df<-subset(df,df$date2<df$date1) 
# translate the days
df %>% dplyr::mutate(Week = ifelse(Week=="Thursday", "quinta-feira", Week),
                 Week = ifelse(Week=="Friday", "sexta-feira", Week),
                 Week = ifelse(Week=="Saturday", "sábado", Week)) -> df

dim_data<-dim(df)

day<-c(seq.Date(from = as.Date(df$date2[1]),
                to = as.Date(df$date2[dim_data[1]]),
                by = "1 day"))

df_grouped <- df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date)) %>% 
  group_by(date2) %>% 
  summarise(Id = first(Id),
            date1 = first(date1),
            Week = first(Week),
            D = first(D),
            D1 = sum(D1)) %>% 
  select(Id,date1,date2,Week,D,D1)

df_grouped <- df_grouped %>% mutate(date1=format(date1,"%d/%m/%Y"),
                                    date2=format(date2,"%d/%m/%Y"))
df_grouped<-data.frame(df_grouped)


#create scatter plot
scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
  
  # get the week day
  my_day <- weekdays(as.Date(dt))
  
  df_OC<-subset(df_grouped,is.na(D)) 
  ds_OC<-subset(df_OC,df_OC$Week==my_day) # omit 'i' and DS
  
  
  mean_Week<-mean(as.numeric(ds_OC[,"D1"]) )
  sdeviation_Week<-sd(as.numeric(ds_OC[,"D1"]))

  
  mean_Week_pos <- (mean_Week + sdeviation_Week)
  mean_Week_neg <- (mean_Week - sdeviation_Week)
  dta %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dt)) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
    plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7),
         main = paste0(my_day, ": (", mean_Week, ",+",mean_Week_pos, ",-", mean_Week_neg,")"),
         ylim = c((min(.$val) %/% 10) * 10, (max(.$val) %/% 10 + 1) * 15))
  abline(h=mean_Week, col='blue') 
  abline(h= mean_Week_pos, col='green',lty=2) 
  abline(h= mean_Week_neg, col='orange',lty=2)
  

}  


scatter_date("2021-04-10",df)
scatter_date("2021-04-9",df)
scatter_date("2021-04-8",df)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Domingo! The three straight lines, that is, mean, mean+standard deviation and mean - standard deviation did not appear to me, did they appear to you?

Comment: I edited my asnwer to extract `mean_Week_pos` and `mean_Week_neg`, then you can see that the `sdeviation_Week` at Thuesday is NA, that is why you only see the blue line, on the two other days I see all lines

Comment: I edited as you said, and no lines appear for me in any of the three images. Strange right, I'll put the images of the figures for you to see.

Comment: Domingo, I inserted the three images for you to see. Basically I took your code and put it to run. What do you think it might be?

Comment: It could be that the function `weekday` returns the weekdays in english you can try to translate the weekdays by hand with a switch statment like I did with the mean in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68947740/adjust-line-in-graph-in-r/68948847#68948847 or maybe this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099990/r-lubridate-weekdays-in-local-language