# Adjust line in graph in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

The graph below generates a scatter plot based on `date2`. In addition, a horizontal line that refers to the mean is generated. Each day of the week has a different mean as you can see.

Note that in abline I specified `h=mean_saturday`, as 10/4 is a Saturday. But I didn't want to always have to change this part of the abline to show the right mean line, but my idea is to leave it automatically, that is, when I enter the date 10/4/2021 in the code, the code already recognize that the 10th it's Saturday and inserts the appropriate mean line. Any idea how to do this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
df <- structure(
  list(Id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
       date1 = c("2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20",
                 "2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20",
                 "2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20",
                 "2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20"),
       date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-04-02",
                 "2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-03",
                 "2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-08",
                 "2021-04-09","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-04-10"),
       Week= c("Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday",
               "Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Thursday",
               "Thursday","Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday"),
       D = c("","","Ho","","","","","","Ho","","","","","","","","","","","",""), 
       DR01 = c(2,1,4,3,3,4,1,6,3,7,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,2,3)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))

mean_thursday=4
mean_friday=5
mean_saturday=6


scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
  dta %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dt)) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
    plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7),
         ylim = c((min(.$val) %/% 10) * 10, (max(.$val) %/% 10 + 1) * 15))
  abline(h=mean_saturday, col='blue') 
}  
scatter_date("2021-04-10",df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to convert the input date in your `scatter_date` function to a date and get the weekday: `my_day <- weekdays(as.Date(dt))` add that to a switch statment for your means:

```
my_mean <- switch(
  my_day,
  "Saturday" = mean_saturday,
  "Friday" = mean_friday,
  "Thursday" = mean_thursday,
  0) # add here your other days
```

and replace `mean_saturday` in `abline(h=mean_saturday, col='blue')` with `my_mean`

here the full code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
df <- structure(
  list(Id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
       date1 = c("2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20",
                 "2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20",
                 "2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20",
                 "2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20","2021-07-20"),
       date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-04-02",
                 "2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-03",
                 "2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-08",
                 "2021-04-09","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-04-10"),
       Week= c("Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday",
               "Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Thursday",
               "Thursday","Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday"),
       D = c("","","Ho","","","","","","Ho","","","","","","","","","","","",""), 
       DR01 = c(2,1,4,3,3,4,1,6,3,7,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,2,3)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))

mean_thursday=4
mean_friday=5
mean_saturday=6


scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
  
  my_day <- weekdays(as.Date(dt))
  
  my_mean <- switch(
    my_day,
    "Saturday" = mean_saturday,
    "Friday" = mean_friday,
    "Thursday" = mean_thursday,
    0) # add here your other days
  
  dta %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dt)) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
    plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7), main = paste0(my_day, ":", my_mean),
         ylim = c((min(.$val) %/% 10) * 10, (max(.$val) %/% 10 + 1) * 15))
  abline(h=my_mean, col='blue') 
}  
# testing the different means
scatter_date("2021-04-10",df)
scatter_date("2021-04-9",df)
scatter_date("2021-04-8",df)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define a `data.frame` containing the mean for the days of interest and then use `weekdays` to extract the corresponding mean from that table.

Instead of

```
mean_thursday=4
mean_friday=5
mean_saturday=6
```

I would go for something like:

```
mean_df <- data.frame(mean = c(4:6),
                      day = c('Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'))
```

and then

```
abline(h=subset(mean_df, day == weekdays(as.Date(dt)))$mean, col='blue')
```

which will be the only change in your function.